# Jquery: .html() substitute the text in a div tag, but how do I add to instead of substitute?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to JQuery. Got a simple question.

```
<div id="result"> hello </div>

...

$("#result").html()
```

`$("#result").html()` substitutes the text inside div tag to the returned result I need, but how do I adding the returned result in div tag instead of changing it completely? I guess there might be another function to do this job. What is it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Just use

```
$("#result").append("Some text");
```

And this will add Some text to the end of your string. 
So it would look like hello Some text

Answer (score 0):

You can use callback function of `.html()`:

```
$("#result").html(function(i,oldhtml){
  return oldhtml + "<span>abc</span>";
})
```